# Silly question: answering ones' own questions?

Tags: discussion

Possibly a silly question, but got to ask it - is there any particular limit to how many of our own questions we can answer?

Just looking at the stats, about 10 or so out of the 86 or so unanswered questions are mine - I have since found new information, would there be anything terrible if I were to answer them with the information I have found?

Comment: It could have been amusing if you would have answered this on your own.

Comment: That did cross my mind

Comment: http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer and http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/self-learner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the official position of SE on this is that it is specifically encouraged (see [the relevant help page](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)), there is no specific limitation.
The only limitation is on accepting your own answer, which has to wait 48 hours after posting it.
As far as the community goes, as long as the question is good, and the answer well documented, i don't think anyone will have a problem with that. The only downside might be that it *might* dissuade some people from posting their own answers, but since you're talking about old unanswered questions of yours, i don't think it applies here.

Comment: Excellent, I would probably not accept an answer to a question I wrote - would not feel right (for me anyway)